# View not receiving ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED when DragShadow enters View - Drag And Drop

Tags: android, kotlin, view, drag-and-drop

I am implementing Drag and Drop feature in my app. I have an object A and an object B. I have registered OnDragListener on the object A and the object B will be dragged and dropped in the object B. I am getting issue while getting the ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED event.

I have found discrepancy in the Android Developer Page regarding how the view receives the drag event.

At [one place](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/drag-drop#AboutDragEvent) it says, the view listening for event will receive the drag event if the **DragShadow** intersects with the Bounding Box of view.
At [another place](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/DragEvent#ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED) it says, the view listening for event will receive the drag event when the **Touch Point** intersects with the Bounding Box of the view.

I need to trigger something when the DragShadow intersects with the view listening for event. But I am gettimng callback only when the **touch point** while dragging the DragShadow enters the view.

Here is how I start Drag And Drop:

```
binding.rlPipette.setOnLongClickListener { v ->
        val item = ClipData.Item(v.tag as CharSequence)
        val mimeTypes = arrayOf(MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)
        val dragData = ClipData(v.tag.toString(), mimeTypes, item)
        updateDragShadow()
        v.startDragAndDrop(dragData, myShadowBuilder, null, DRAG_FLAG_OPAQUE)
        v.translationZ = -1f
        true
    }
```

Here is how I attach listener and listens for event:

```
binding.ivTube1.setOnDragListener(this)


override fun onDrag(v: View?, event: DragEvent?): Boolean {
    Log.e("notifyIntersection", event?.action.toString())
    event?.let {
        when (it.action) {
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED -> {
                return true
            }
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED -> {
                viewModel.notifyIntersection(v?.tag as Int, it.action)
            }
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED -> {
                viewModel.notifyIntersection(v?.tag as Int, it.action)
                updateDragShadow()
            }
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION -> {
            }
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED -> {
                binding.rlPipette.translationZ = 0f
            }
            DragEvent.ACTION_DROP -> {
            }
        }
        return true
    } ?: return false
}
```